# Display all unicode characters in Emacs under OS X

Tags: emacs, unicode, iterm2

First of all, please look at this screenshot [image: GUI vs iTerm]

I have GUI Emacs installed via Homebrew on the left and another one running inside iTerm2 with `-nw` option on the right. Both of them are using `Droid Sans Mono` font.

But, as you can see, the right one can perfectly handle all unicode characters. I think iTerm2 helps here:

- on the left `display` says that there is no font available
- on the right `display` is equal to `terminal code #xF0 #x9F #x8D #xBA`

How can I achieve the same result in GUI Emacs as I can have in iTerm2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I finally managed this issue with these lines in my emacs config:

```
;; set proper language (fixes cyrillic letters in ansi-term)
(setenv "LANG" "ru_RU.UTF-8")

;; default font
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Droid Sans Mono")

;; font for all unicode characters
(set-fontset-font t 'unicode "Symbola" nil 'prepend)

;; override font for cyrillic characters
(set-fontset-font t 'cyrillic "Droid Sans Mono")
```

The first line can be ignored, as it only for fixing cyrillic letters in `ansi-term`.

The steps are:

- set your default font with `set-face-attribute`
- then set different font for the specific character-sets via `set-fontset-font`

Of course, I'll need to set specific range of characters for Symbola font, but it works for me now.

P.S. but I still can't get colored emoji in Emacs as I have in iTerm2

Comment: this problem had plagued me for a while. i needed "Apple Color Emoji" instead of "Symbola" but other than that your fontset notion worked beautifully for me. thank you.

Comment: Correction – "Apple Color Emoji" used to work. Now Emacs intentionally disabled emoji on MacOS – https://swsnr.de/posts/bye-bye-emojis-emacs-hates-macos